# Windows Docker Container finds ODBC when run on my machine but not on the server

Tags: python, windows, docker, odbc, driver

The container runs fine on my local machine, but when running on the server the ODBC Driver does not show up in the list of servers. I should not need a DSN as I don't have one on my local machine. has anyone run across this issue. Possibly a server setting?

> Error: InterfaceError('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.10.10-windowsservercore-1809 as base 
    WORKDIR "C:\src"
    COPY vc_redist.x64.exe c:/
    COPY msodbcsql_18.3.2.1.msi c:/
    RUN c:\\vc_redist.x64.exe /install /passive /norestart 
    RUN MSIEXEC /UNREGISTER
    RUN MSIEXEC /REGSERVER
    RUN msiexec.exe /i C:\\msodbcsql_18.3.2.1.msi /norestart /qn /quiet 
    /passive IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES 
    #RUN apt-get install -y C:\\msodbcsql_18.3.2.1.msi
    #RUN msiexec /quiet /passive /qn /i msodbcsql.msi 
    IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES ADDLOCAL=ALL 
    #RUN  Start-Process   'c:/msodbcsql_18.3.2.1.msi' '/qn /norestart /L*V "odbc.log"' -PassThru | Wait-Process;

    RUN pip install "poetry==1.4.0"

    COPY my.lock .
    COPY my.toml .

    RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true
    RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

    COPY ["myPgm.py", "."]
    COPY ["myJsonFile.json", "."]

    CMD ["poetry","run", 
    "python","myPgm.py","Param1","Param2","Param3","Param4","Parm5"]
```

Running the container locally on my machine where it works fine.  When running on the server it
does NOT find the ODBC Driver.  It only finds the native SQL Server Driver.

On my machine (both drivers found):

```
2023-12-20 14:49:49.511504  Installed Driver #1 ... SQL Server
2023-12-20 14:49:49.511504  Installed Driver #2 ... ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
```

On Server (Only SQL Server default driver found):

```
2023-12-20 14:09:36.276160  Installed Driver #1 ...SQL Server
```

Comment: I've tried to reformat your question as precisely as I could, but the last line does not look right to me, with its spurious closing square bracket. Can you verify the Dockerfile code to make sure it's identical here to what you have on your machine?

Comment: Thanks, Joanis, I saw you were formatting as I make a couple of changes.  It's my first post and I think some of the formatting is off a bit.  I just updated now and hopefully it's better.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, we used a work-around by creating an image on a local Windows 10 PC using Docker Save and then doing a docker load on the server.  The dockerfile then references the loaded image on the server using the "From" statement.

Comment: this looks like a comment and not the answer.